# How find this ODE solution $\frac{f(x)}{f(a)}=\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^2e^{(x-a)\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}-\frac{2}{x}\right)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

let $a>0$ is constant number,and   the function $f(x)$ such follow ODE
$$\dfrac{f(x)}{f(a)}=\left(\dfrac{x}{a}\right)^2e^{(x-a)\left(\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}-\dfrac{2}{x}\right)}$$

Find the $f(x)?$

Thank you

My try: 
$$\dfrac{f(x)}{x^2}=\dfrac{f(a)}{a^2}e^{(x-a)\left(\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}-\dfrac{2}{x}\right)}$$
then
$$\ln{\dfrac{f(x)}{x^2}}-\ln{\dfrac{f(a)}{a^2}}=(x-a)\left(\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}-\dfrac{2}{x}\right)$$

then I can't,Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Your equation can be written as follows:

$$\frac{\ln\frac{f(x)}{f(a)} - \ln\frac{x^2}{a^2}}{x-a} + \frac{2}{x} = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}, $$

now make the substitution: $\phi = \ln{f}$, so it yields:

$$\phi' = f'/f,$$

and substitute back in the original ode, which gives:

$$\phi' -  \frac{1}{x-a} \phi = \frac{2}{x}(x-a) - \ln\frac{x^2}{f(a) \, a^2}   := Q(x).$$

This is a linear first order ODE for $\phi(x)$, which can be solved, for example, in terms of an integrating factor, $u = e^{- \int (1/(x-a)) \,dx} = 1/(x-a) $, so:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{\phi}{x-a} \right) = \frac{Q}{x-a} \, dx,$$

and hence the solution:

$$\phi = A + (x-a)\int\frac{Q}{x-a}\,dx,$$

or, in terms of $f(x)$:

$$f = e^\phi = \overline{A} e^{(x-a) \int \frac{Q}{x-a} \, dx},$$

where I have defined $\overline{A} = e^A$, being $A$ a constant of integration.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could turn it into a first order linear differential equation by substituting $\ln(f)=\phi$, since $\phi'=\ln(f)'=\frac{f'}{f}$ appears on the right side.

Comment: then ? I can't follow,Thank you